# Seeking a derangement $S: \{0,1\}^4 \to \{0,1\}^4$ for which changing one bit in the input always changes at least two bits in the output

Tags: functions, permutations

Kindly asking for any hints about the following question:

Define a function $ S : \{0,1\}^4 \to \{0,1\}^4$ with this conditions:

1- For any $x$, $\ S(x) \neq x $

2- for any $x \neq y$, $\ S(x) \neq S(y).$

3- Changed one bit in the input always changing at least two bits in the output.

Comment: What about $n\mapsto 3n+1\mod 16$?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I think the third condition is not checked since $0001\mapsto 0100$ and $0101\mapsto 0000$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not getting systematically, I looked for solutions (there seem tobe gazillions) by backtracking
Try this
$$ 0000\mapsto 0001\\
0001\mapsto0010\\
0010\mapsto0100\\
0011\mapsto0111\\
0100\mapsto0110\\
0101\mapsto1000\\
0110\mapsto0011\\
0111\mapsto1101\\
1000\mapsto1010\\
1001\mapsto0101\\
1010\mapsto1111\\
1011\mapsto1100\\
1100\mapsto1001\\
1101\mapsto1110\\
1110\mapsto0000\\
1111\mapsto1011$$

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be the function that shifts each bit to the left (except from $0000$ and $1111$). Mathematically, it can be described as
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1111 &\text{if }x=0000\\
0000 &\text{if }x=1111\\
2x \mod{15} &\text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
EDIT: I just realized that the third condition is not fulfilled.